Save File to Folder Based on Cell Values
I have two Subs that I would like to work together. One to create a new folder, if it doesn't already exist and the second to SaveAs with the file name based on cell values.
I would like for the code to

create the folder (if needed)
SaveAs with new file name (based on cell values)
Place new file in the folder created.

So far I have items 1 and 2 working independently, but the moment have yet to be able to get the workbook to save to the folder created.
Option Explicit
'----- declare the base path here -----
Const MYPATH As String = "I:\test\"

Sub CreateFolder()

Dim fldNamea As String
Dim fldNameb As String
    
    fldNamea = Range("BL5").Value
    fldNameb = Range("W4").Value

    'Create Directory
    If Len(Dir(MYPATH & "Audit " & fldNamea & " " & fldNameb, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir MYPATH & "Audit " & fldNamea & " " & fldNameb
    End If

End Sub

Sub wbNewFileName()
    
Dim fldNamea As String
Dim fldNameb As String
Dim fldPath As String
Dim wbName As String

    CreateFolder

    fldNamea = Range("BL5").Value 'Report Number
    fldNameb = Range("W4").Value 'Report Name
    fldPath = MYPATH & fldNamea & fldNameb & "\" 'Folder Path
    
    ' Save file to directory
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    Filename:=fldPath & fldNamea & "Report - " & fldNameb & ".xlsm", _
    FileFormat:=52, _
    CreateBackup:=False

    MsgBox "Successfully Saved"

End Sub


With CreateFolderyou create a folder which starts with Audit but you do not use this in wbNewFileName. You also put Report -  between fldNamea and fldnameb  in the Filename which does not fit to the created folder at all.

Make CreateFolder a function which returns the path of the folder - you can call it from wbNewFileName

A quick fix for wbNewFileName could be
Sub SaveWorkbookToFolder()
    Dim fldNamea As String
    Dim fldNameb As String
    Dim fldPath As String
    
    CreateFolder
    
    fldNamea = Range("BL5").Value ' Report Number
    fldNameb = Range("W4").Value ' Report Name
    ' added Audit to the Path
    fldPath = MYPATH & "Audit " & fldNamea & " " & fldNameb & "\" ' Folder Path
    
    ' Save file to directory
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
        Filename:=fldPath & fldNamea & "Report - " & fldNameb & ".xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=52, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    
    MsgBox "Successfully Saved"
End Sub

A bit more robust approach would be
    Function createFolder(fldPath As String)
        
        If Dir(fldPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            Shell ("cmd /c mkdir """ & fldPath & """")
        End If
        
    End Function
    
Sub main()
    Dim fldNamea As String
    Dim fldNameb As String
    Dim fldPath As String
    
    fldNamea = Range("BL5").Value
    fldNameb = Range("W4").Value
    
    fldPath = MYPATH & "Audit " & fldNamea & " " & fldNameb
    createFolder fldPath
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
        Filename:=fldPath & fldNamea & "Report - " & fldNameb & ".xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=52, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    
    MsgBox "Successfully Saved"
    
End Sub


With both replies, the folder creation part works well, but I keep getting Run-Time error '1004' Method 'SaveAs' of object'_workbook' failed when it tries to save the file into the created folder. Being new to Excel vba, any help would be appreciated

Could you provide the actual value of fldPath,  fldNamea and fldNameb ?

fldPath will be the folder that has just been created, where fldNamea & fldNameb will change, according to the values within those cells

Sorry, you did not get it. Debug the code, look at the current values of those variables and check if you have got  a valid filename after all. Not every string is a valid foldername resp. filename! If you do not know how to debug google for it. You should get a lot of hits. Debugging is an essential skill in programming, so worth learning it

thank you for the help, after using the debugging tools available, I found that there was an error in my original file path (MYPATH).

'SaveAs' a Workbook
Main
Sub SaveWithNewFileName()
    
    Const ROOT_PATH As String = "C:\Test\T2024\78639123\" ' "I:\test\"
    Const FOLDER_LEFT As String = "Audit"
    Const FILE_MIDDLE As String = "Report -"
    Const FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".xlsm"
    Const FILE_FORMAT As Long = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Const CREATE_BACKUP As Boolean = False
    Const REPORT_NUMBER_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "BL5"
    Const REPORT_NAME_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "W4"
     
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim ReportNumber As String:
    ReportNumber = CStr(ws.Range(REPORT_NUMBER_CELL_ADDRESS).Value)
    If Len(ReportNumber) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The report number is missing!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim ReportName As String:
    ReportName = CStr(ws.Range(REPORT_NAME_CELL_ADDRESS).Value)
    If Len(ReportName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The report name is missing!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = GetFolderPath( _
        ROOT_PATH, FOLDER_LEFT, ReportNumber, ReportName)
    If Len(FolderPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim FileBaseName As String: FileBaseName = GetFileBaseName( _
        ReportNumber, FILE_MIDDLE, ReportName)
    
    Dim FileExtension As String: FileExtension = FILE_EXTENSION
    If Left(FileExtension, 1) <> "." Then FileExtension = "." & FileExtension
    
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = FolderPath & FileBaseName & FileExtension
    
    With ws.Parent
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
            On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if invalid file name
                .SaveAs Filename:=FilePath, FileFormat:=FILE_FORMAT, _
                    CreateBackup:=CREATE_BACKUP
            On Error GoTo 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    
    If Len(Dir(FilePath)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not save as """ & FilePath & """!", vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "File saved successfully.", vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub

Help
Function GetFolderPath( _
    RootPath As String, _
    LeftFolderName As String, _
    ReportNumber As String, _
    ReportName As String, _
    Optional Delimiter As String = " ") _
As String
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    
    Dim FolderPath As String:
    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
    FolderPath = RootPath & LeftFolderName & Delimiter _
        & ReportNumber & Delimiter & ReportName & pSep
        
    If Len(Dir(FolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir FolderPath
    
    GetFolderPath = FolderPath
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Function GetFileBaseName( _
    ReportNumber As String, _
    MiddleFileName As String, _
    ReportName As String, _
    Optional Delimiter As String = " ") _
As String
    GetFileBaseName = ReportNumber & Delimiter _
        & MiddleFileName & Delimiter & ReportName
End Function

